# Saving results from three for-loop as a vector

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing

[let's say that we have three vectors `b1`, `b2`, and `b3` and I need to loop over all their possible value combinations and store their product in a new vector. For example,

```
b1 <- seq(0.2, 2, by=0.2)
b2 <- seq(0.2, 2, by=0.2)
b3 <- seq(0.2, 2, by=0.2)

product <- vector()

for (i in 1:length(b1))
{
  for (j in 1:length(b2))
  {
    for (k in 1:length(b3))
    {
      product[i] <- b1[i]*b2[j]*b3[k]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem now is that product stores only 10 values. How can I fix this index problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the indexing problem in loop, you can add a new variable lets say `counter` which increments for every iteration in the loop.

```
counter <- 1
for (i in 1:length(b1)) {
   for (j in 1:length(b2))  {
     for (k in 1:length(b3)) {
       product[counter] <- b1[i]*b2[j]*b3[k]
       counter = counter + 1
    }
  }
}
```

---

You can also use `outer` which would give you the same result.

```
c(outer(b3, c(outer(b1, b2))))
```

If there are multiple such vectors put them in a list and use `Reduce`

```
c(Reduce(outer, list(b1, b2, b3)))
```

Note that `outer` expects a function to be applied to the combination of vectors but since multiplication (`*`) is the default function we do not mention it here.